# Adding properties to an existing type in a different files with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a file that has `type` or `interface` variable (all these variables are export) and I need to add new properties for this variable from different files without extends. I mean change on the same variable from different files.

example:
file a:

```
export interface ButtonPresentationProps {
    buttonType?: "outline" | "solid";
    variant?: ButtonVariants;
}
```

and I need from `file b` add new properties to the interface without a create new interface variable because I'm using the interface in a different place.

How can do that?

Comment: You're looking for declaration merging.

Answer (score 0):

Use declare -

For an already extended -

```
import { ButtonPresentationProps } from "./myfile";
```

...you would use -

```
declare "./myfile" {
    export interface ButtonPresentationProps {
        buttonType?: "outline" | "solid";
        variant?: ButtonVariants;
    }
}
```

So long as it's somewhere in the compile chain it will be used, so normally useful sticking in a *.d.ts file and importing directly - but feel free to stick in the same file as it's being used.

Comment: Just to note that this will work on any input file - even libraries etc - so a good way to fix things that aren't correct etc :-)

Comment: I have created 2 files A and B
A File: 
interface MyInterface {
    name: string;
}

export default MyInterface;

B File: 
import MyInterface from './A';

declare module './A' {
    interface MyInterface {
        age: number;
    }
}

and in The Main.ts
const test: MyInterface = {
    name: "Test",
    age: 5,
}


but it returns error "Type '{ name: string; age: number; }' is not assignable to type 'MyInterface'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'age' does not exist in type 'MyInterface'."

Comment: you can see my code here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63495732/14133817

Comment: My fault - forgot to add `export` to the second. As an aside, you shouldn't use `export default` if you can help it - it makes far more problems than it solves - https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/defaultisbad